# Getting attachments from Facebook conversations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently use the Facebook Graph API to get a inbox conversation. Most of the messages look like this:

```
{
  "id": "1452301718360191_1407164668", 
  "from": {
    "id": "10203840837848742", 
    "name": "Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen"
  }, 
  "message": "Some message", 
  "created_time": "2014-08-04T15:04:28+0000"
}
```

However, some of the messages in the conversation are images, and they are represented like this:

```
{
  "id": "1452301718360191_1407164668", 
  "from": {
    "id": "10203840837848742", 
    "name": "Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2014-08-04T15:04:28+0000"
}
```

So basically what is different is that the message is gone. But since there is no mention of the attachment, or url to the image or anything else I can use, I'm not able to display the image in my app.

So my question is: How can I get a hold of the image (or url to the image). Hopefully it will be available in some way when I have the message ID.

Answer (score 0):

With **Graph api V2** the egde to retrieve inbox messages is `/id/conversations`
`id` is eitheir a user id or a page id
Each conversation message with attachment should return an "`attachments`" field.
Then for each  message with attachment you should query the url `https://api.facebook.com/method/messaging.getattachment?mid=message_id&access_tokes=your_access_token`

Note that **it does not work with graph api v2.1**. Unless you curl the query